# Captcha Validation and Send Email

Tags: php

I have an issue with the validating and further processing Captcha on my form. I would like to confirm the answer is correct then send out the email and send the user to the thank you page otherwise take it to the error page if the user failed to input the proper response to the Captcha. I am capturing the captcha code on a hidden input field on the form. Even after putting in the correct code, it still redirects me to the error.html page I have set up.

See code below I use the 'captcha_code', where I am trying to obtain the value of true/false. Once the answer is either true or false based on that it'll continue the IF statement of either sending an email or taking it to the Thank-You page.

(If there is any code I am missing to post, please do let me know I'll have that code posted up immediately.)

PHP Code: (Updated Code Post Comments Below) *Still being directed to the Error page even if the captcha is correct.

```
    <?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
$companyName = $_POST['tscpCompanyName'];
$businessType = $_POST['tscpBusinessType'];
$yearsBusiness = $_POST['tscpYears'];
$numberOfUnits = $_POST['tscpNumberOfUnits'];
$firstName = $_POST['tscpFirstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['tscpLastName'];
$email = $_POST['tscpEmail'];
$number = $_POST['tscpNumber'];
$vals = $_POST['vals'];
$human = intval($_POST['captcha_code']);

$from = "From:test@from.com";
$to = "test@to.com";
$subject = 'Custom Package Request';

$body ="Company Name: $companyName\n\n Business Type: $businessType\n\n Years In Business: $yearsBusiness\n\n First Name: $firstName\n\n Last Name: $lastName\n\n Email: $email\n\n Number: $number\n\n Services: $vals\n\n";


if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if ($_POST['captcha_code'] == $_SESSION['code']) {
echo 'true';
} else {
echo 'false';
}

//Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
if ($human !== false) {
    $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
}
// If there are no errors, send the email

if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        header("Location: /thank-you/mortgage-lending.html");
    } else {
        header("Location: /error.html");
    }
}
else {
    header("Location: /error.html");
}
}?>
```

Comment: use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: What happens currently?

Comment: So... what is your problem?

Comment: @chris85 Currently when i submit the form and accepts the captcha it takes me to the error page.

Comment: obvious, your if statement failed and I have a feeling why

Comment: also Error.html is not the same as error.html which if on Linux, one of them will fail and add exit; after each header

Comment: I updated the "error.html" so I would not have the issue you suggested would occur. I also updated $GET to $POST still unable to obtain the information. Am I missing something really small?

Comment: see the answer given below. we don't know what your HTML form looks like, so I won't be able to help any further. You also tagged as javascript with no code to support the question

Comment: you also changed your question from $_GET to $_POST without marking it as an edit. Something that an answer given below pointed out. I hope you upvoted the answer, if you have enough rep points that is.

Answer (score 2):

You are posting the form with post.  So, use `$_POST` for captcha, not `$_GET`

Comment: OP made a stealth edit to the question, without marking it as an edit. *Lovely, isn't it?*

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution to the problem. I first and foremost updated the IF statement that would mail out and redirect me to correct page. I also made sure to updated my $POST & session_start().

Here is the PHP Code:

```
  <?php
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

   if ($_POST["submit"]) 
   {
    $companyName        = $_POST['tscpCompanyName'];
    $businessType   = $_POST['tscpBusinessType'];
    $yearsBusiness  = $_POST['tscpYears'];
    $numberOfUnits  = $_POST['tscpNumberOfUnits'];
    $firstName          = $_POST['tscpFirstName'];
    $lastName           = $_POST['tscpLastName'];
    $email                  = $_POST['tscpEmail'];
    $number                 = $_POST['tscpNumber'];
    $vals                   = $_POST['vals'];
    $human                  = intval($_POST['captcha_code']);
    $captchaError= FALSE;

    $from = "From:test@from.com";
    $to = "test@test.com";
    $subject = 'Custom Package Request';

    $body ="Company Name: $companyName\n\n Business Type: $businessType\n\n Years In Business: $yearsBusiness\n\n First Name: $firstName\n\n Last Name: $lastName\n\n Email: $email\n\n Number: $number\n\n Services: $vals\n\n";

    if ($_POST['captcha_code'] != $_SESSION['code']) 
    {
    $captchaError = TRUE;
    $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
    }

    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$captchaError) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    header("Location: /thank-you/mortgage-lending.html");
    } else {
    header("Location: /error.html");
    }
    }
    else {
header("Location: /error.html");
    }
    }?>
```

Comment: so, what's the difference? You posted code that fixed your problem, but didn't explain it, nor mentioned which changes were made to fix the problem. You also need to think about future visitors to the question/answer.